# How do I calculate the internal home network speed between two computers?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

What should I use if I want to determine the speed between two (Windows) machines in my internal home network?

My current technique involves copying a large file between the two and then manually calculating the MB/s.

I could use the Windows copy dialogue (example below) but the speed tends to shoot all over the place rather than have any kind of consistency.

[image]

Is there is a better, easier and more accurate way to do this?

Comment: What are you measuring it for? It's true there are other tools for testing this. But, most likely you are more concerned about "quality" rather than "speed." The "speed" is whatever the slowest network interface is operating at between the two devices. FYI, the speed of an individual file transfer usually does not "shoot all over the place" unless there is a quality issue. It will stabilize and settle at a consistent speed. It helps to know what you are trying to measure and why.

Comment: I suspect you're speed I'd all over the place because you are copying small files. Copying a large file off an ssd or defragged disk is likely to give you a better value if you don't want to download "proper" tools.

Answer (score 0):

IPerf is a quick, easy, flexible, cross-platform, free, and open source network performance tool that many networking pros use for performance measurements.

It's originally a command-line tool, but people have wrapped GUIs around it for various platforms.